# swiping tile is not working on animation images

Tags: java, selenium, appium

swiping tile is working for all other tile/images except animation images like weather screen.here is my working code for swiping normal tile/image.

```
public static void swipeTile(AppiumDriver driver, MobileElement element) {
    try {
           element.isDisplayed();

           int startX = Math.toIntExact(Math.round(element.getSize().getWidth())); 
           int endX = Math.toIntExact(Math.round(element.getSize().getWidth() / 2));
           int startY = element.getLocation().getY();

           TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
           action.longPress(startX,startY).waitAction(500).moveTo(endX, startY).release().perform(); 
          driver.performTouchAction(action); 

    }  
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you want to scroll into page or what please share with us what exactly you want to do

Comment: i want to swipe a tile image to left.its a container one present at a time if i swipe first image left in the container the next one will appear.these two images have different id also. id's like weather_details_today_container_0 and weather_details_today_container_1

Comment: will you share link to the image or share screenshot

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QLjMyrZFGLLJf1OutdH9aJjBaBK8dN8M/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have seen their is already Carousel button (small rounded button to move from one image to another)  if you click that then you can easily jump from one image to another then also if you want to use your code to do the automation then you can i have share the link so you can see and let us know if that works or not

http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/02/how-to-move-seekbar-with-appium.html

Comment: Thanks akshay for the link.its working i made it int end = element.getSize().getWidth() / 2; otherwise cordinates going out of the element

Comment: there is one problem.its swiping to left on the tile which i shared image(animating) with you.but the normal tile in another page its trying to swipe reverse direction.